# Hibernate postgresql time difference in model data type

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, types, timestamp, formula

I have a PostgreSQL table with two timestamp columns and a corresponding hibernate model. Now I want to create a new @formula field which stores the difference between these two fields like answer_ts - invite_ts.

What should be the right java data type to map this formula.

Thanks,
Kaushik